# Check if a Database exists or not

Tags: c#, mysql

I am attempting to set up a method to check if a database exists, and return true/false.

Is it possible to do this with MySQL? Or would it be better off using a method in c#?

What I have so far:

```
public bool TestDbConnection()
{
    try
    {
        mySqlConnect = new MySqlConnection(mySqlConnectionString);
        mySqlConnect.Open();

        // Check if <database_name> exists

        if (<database_name>.Exists)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else { return false; }   
    }
    catch (MySQLException e) { }

    if (mySqlConnect != null)
    {
        mySqlConnect.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `database_name`?

Comment: @KirkWoll the name of the database. I.e. "db_users"

Comment: That can't possibly be true, as the string `"db_users"` does not contain the method `Exists`.

Comment: Yeah, I realise that. I was attempting to create an example of what I was trying to achieve. Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: ok, gotcha.  That's a good approach, just didn't realize that was what you were doing.